# How to allow calls from localhost through Nginx Auth?

Tags: nginx

I am using the following code :

```
location / {  
  satisfy any;  
  allow 127.0.0.1;  
  deny all;  
  auth_basic "closed site";  
  auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;  
}
```

But when I do `curl -I "http://mysite.com"` it returns 401 :(
how do I allow localhost?

Edit :
The machine I am using this on is an amazon ec2 instance.

Ok,

I didn't realize that amazon ec2 instance will call its external/public IP when you call mysite.com :)

How silly.

So I am accepting @Capilé's answer for the hosts file workaround he mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct, but probably mysite.com is not reaching the 127.0.0.1 interface of your server. If you try `curl -I "http://127.0.0.1"` (or any localhost aliases), you should get it.

Alternatively, you might add mysite.com to 127.0.0.1 through /etc/hosts (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on windows):

```
127.0.0.1  mysite.com
```

Cheers,

Comment: So I've `allow 127.0.0.1`'d my nginx, and when I go to 127.0.0.1/passwd_dir, I am allowed in with no pwd. But when I go to localhost/passwd_dir, it demands the pwd. How can I allow localhost in addition to 127.0.0.1? `allow localhost` doesn't work, it errors out

Comment: Ah just stumbled across the answer to my own comment by viewing the logs: by default, localhost renders to IPv6, so a simple `allow ::1` fixed my problem.